# Finding the offset of an element within a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<pre>` block that contains 0 or more sections surrounded by `<span>` elements. The `<span>` elements are added by me in response to user-triggered events (using javascript).

I need to find the positions of all those `<span>` elements so that I can save and restore them later to the same block of text in the `<pre>` when the user re-visits the page.

I don't want to simply save the HTML contents of the `<pre>` block because it can be quite large, and this is not efficient. I would rather save the numerical index of the position in the text where each `<span>` starts and ends.

I can use vanilla javascript, alternatively I have jQuery available in this application.

Here is an example:

```
<pre id="test">Hello, <span>world</span></pre>
```

In this case I would like to save the pair [7, 12] as the start and end of the substring to be surrounded by a `span` within the string "Hello, world".

Using jQuery, here is a basic stub for the kind of code that I might end up with:

```
$("#test span").each(function(){
    // find the start and end indexes of $(this) within the parent element's text content, but how?
    // save these 2 digits etc
});
```

I should also say that:

- There are no other elements inside the `pre` other than the `span` elements
- The `span` elements never overlap and are never empty (I have other code which checks for these cases and removes/replaces them as necessary)
- Assume there is just one `pre` or that I can access it by ID as in the above example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this fairly simply in the end. The key was simply to add a unique id attribute to each `<span>`, and then use `indexOf()` to find, for example, `<span id="span_2">` in the `<pre>`'s innerHTML (or `.html()` in jquery) within a jquery `.each()`.

The rest of the problem was complicated only by the need to use a correct offset equal in length to all of the opening and closing `<span>` tags prior to the one in question. This yields a position within the non-HTML text string (`.text()` in jquery) which I can then use to re-insert the `<span>`s later, which I had to do in reverse order (starting from the end of the text string and working to the beginning). This turns text into HTML, so I then replaced the content of the `<pre>` using jquery's `.html(new_version)` rather than `.text()`.

This is conceptually similar to Andomar's answer, but his answer does not give the position of the `<span>` within in the plain text, only within the HTML.

Here is a stripped down version of my code:

```
// example text:
// <pre id="mypre"><span id="span_1" class="highlight">hello</span> world, <span id="span_2" class="highlight">hello</span></pre>
var highlights = [];
var html = $("#mypre").html();
$("#mypre span.highlight").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var highlight_length = $(this).text().length;
    var span = '<span id="'+id+'" class="highlight">';
    var start = html.indexOf(span);
    var offset = 0;
    $("#mypre span.highlight").each(function(){
        var inner_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if(inner_id == id){
            return false;
        }
        var inner_span = '<span id="'+inner_id+'" class="highlight"></span>';
        offset += inner_span.length;
    });
    start -= offset;
    highlights[highlights.length] = [start, highlight_length];
}).promise().done(function(){
    // now I save the collected data (the "highlights" array)
});
```

NB, in my question I asked for the start and end, whereas in my answer I have used the start and length.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#test span").each(function(i,el){
    var parentText = $(el).parent().text();
    var spanText = $(el).text();
    var index1 = parentText.indexOf(spanText);
    var index2 = index1+spanText.length;
    alert('['+index1+','+index2+']');
});
```

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/m6eE2/

Comment: Sadly this, while simple, would not work: there is the possibility that the text would repeat. e.g., <pre>hello, <span>hello</span> world</pre> - your method would give the index1 and index2 as the position of the first "hello" not the second :-(

Comment: Then use the last computed second index as starting point for indexOf. Example with the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6eE2/1/
However it won't work if the text within the span exists prior to the span itself, e.g. "Hello world and <span>world</span>" will not give the correct result. Can this case happen?

Comment: Yes, this case can definitely happen (that is what I said in my previous comment I think, I gave "hello, hello world" with the span around the second "hello").

Comment: Then I guess the html itself should be parsed, something like: http://jsfiddle.net/m6eE2/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the span elements:

```
var txt = $('#test').html();
var pos = -1;
var posList = new Array();
while (true) {
    pos = txt.indexOf("<span>", pos+1);
    if (pos < 0) {
        break;
    }
    var pos1 = pos;        
    pos = txt.indexOf("</span>", pos+1);
    if (pos < 0) {
        break;
    }
    var tuple = {start: pos1, end: pos};
    posList.push(tuple);
};
alert (JSON.stringify(posList));
```

[Example at jsfiddle.net.](http://jsfiddle.net/GxgY5/)